# How to solve Fatal Error in Wordpress 404 Error Page?

Tags: php, wordpress

This shows me whenever I/any user encounters an error page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-content/plugins/permalink-finder_bak/includes/pf-404.php:621 
Stack trace: 
    #0 /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-content/plugins/permalink-finder_bak/includes/pf-404.php(428): kpg_find_permalink_post_exact('expected-questi...', '2', 'N', 'N', 'N') 
    #1 /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-content/plugins/permalink-finder_bak/permalink-finder.php(37): kpg_permalink_fixer() 
    #2 /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): kpg_permalink_finder('') 
    #3 /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) 
    #4 /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
    #5 /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(12): do_action('template_redire...') 
    #6 /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/exampdte/...') 
    #7 /home/exampdte/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/exampdte/...') 
    #8 {main} thrown in /home/exampdte/public_html/wp-content/plugins/permalink-finder_bak/includes/pf-404.php on line 621
```

Comment: Upgrade wordpress, or tell it to use mysqli instead of mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error message it tells you exactly what's going on, let's break it down:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()
```

That means you're getting a Fatal Error (so the current request will die/stop right here), the Fatal Error being `undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()`, which means that the function doesn't exist.

And inside the Stack Trace you can see `/home/exampdte/public_html/wp-content/plugins/permalink-finder_bak/includes/pf-404.php:621` which means this is an issue on that file on line `621`.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` (and the rest of the `mysql_` functions) have been deprecated and replace with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and related `mysqli_` functions.

So you either have an outdated version of the `permalink-finder_bak` plugin, or you need to deactivate it if they stopped maintaining it.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot :)